# Adding value attribut without removing old one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to add value atribute through jquery, but not to remove the old atribut (something like addClass).I have 7 input fields that is typed, and need to combine it in one word and passed to another input field. I tried to take value from typed field and passed it to field that all of them need to be combined, but it always take value from last field when I tried with

```
$("input").keyup(function(){
    var test = this.value;
    $(".solution_2").attr('value', test);
});
```

Here is html:

```
<input id="1" class="q1 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1"  type="text"/>
<input id="2" class="q2 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" />

<input class="solution_2" value="" class="form-control" type="text" name="date">
```

Any ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Get / read first value and concatenate new one to that  and  assign that to input field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `map` and `join` to get all the values. So, you don't need to store or add value in different attribute. Check the below code:

```js
$("button").on('click', function() {
  var finalValue = $('input').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get().join('');
  console.log(finalValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="1" class="q1 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" />
<input id="2" class="q2 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1" type="text" />

<input class="solution_2" value="" class="form-control" type="text" name="date">

<button class="someClass">Get Value</button>
```

Comment: this solution is good, only it displays all solution (for example if I type a, then b, then c, it put value aababc, and I need only the last one), and somehove put male text on the end (amale).

Comment: Comma has been removed. You can try the updated code.

Comment: The comma is gone, but still this is not I am looking for is to store only last one that is typed, so far, it stores every combination (for example if I type a, then b, then c, it put value aababc, and I need only the last one). And also, I do not know why it output word male at the end. Thanks

Comment: So I tried what you mentioned and I am getting correct values. I have changed the trigger to `button`, can you try now? And I didn't understand what you meant by _output word male at the end_?

Comment: Now it is perfect. Thanks. Word male was my mistake, forget about it :)

Answer (score 1):

First you usually get the value in jquery by using `.val()`.

The problem is that you only take the last value and overwrite the old one. You need to take the old value and add the new one.

```
$("input").keyup(function(){
    $(".solution_2").val($(".solution_2").val()+this.val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just get all the value evrytime and send them to solution_2
Something like :

```
$("input").keyup(function(){
    var test = $("#1").attr("value")+$("#2").attr("value");
    $(".solution_2").attr('value', test);
});
```

Btw, you can use val() instead of attr("value");

```
$("input").keyup(function(){
    var test = $("#1").val()+$("#2").val();
    $(".solution_2").val(test);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').on('input',function(){
    var txt = '';
    $('.solution_2').val('');
    $('input').each(function(){
      txt += $(this).val();
    })
    $('.solution_2').val(txt);
  })
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').on('input',function(){
    var txt = '';
    $('.solution_2').val('');
    $('input').each(function(){
      txt += $(this).val();
    })
    $('.solution_2').val(txt);
  })
})

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: true console: false babel: false -->
```

```css
p {
  display: table-row;
}

input,label {
  display: table-cell;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<p><label>character 1:</label><input id="s1" class="q1 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1"  type="text"/></p>
<p><label>character 2:</label><input id="s1" class="q1 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1"  type="text"/></p>
<p><label>character 3:</label><input id="s1" class="q1 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1"  type="text"/></p>
<p><label>character 4:</label><input id="s1" class="q1 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1"  type="text"/></p>
<p><label>character 5:</label><input id="s1" class="q1 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1"  type="text"/></p>
<p><label>character 6:</label><input id="s1" class="q1 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1"  type="text"/></p>
<p><label>character 7:</label><input id="s1" class="q1 inputs letter square border_black" maxlength="1"  type="text"/></p>
<p><label>word:</label><input class="solution_2" value="" class="form-control" type="text" name="date"></p>
```

Comment: @Marko Petković , see my post!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to concatinate the inputs values into a single string?

```
var inputs = $('.inputs');
inputs.keyup(function() {
    $('.solution_2').val(inputs.val().join(''));
});
```